# How to create a HMENU/TMENU with Icons that came from a Mask field (text)?

Tags: mask, typoscript, typo3-9.x

With the extension "Mask" I've added some fields in Page Templates to assign Icons to pages. Also you can use a checkbox to activate the selected icon in menus. Menu meaning this case: I've also made a Content Element with Mask where you only enter a UID and all subpages of that UID will be created as `<li>` list.

I've set up the following fields in Page Templates:

- **page_01_icon** (String): will contain something like "icon-home"

  **page_02_color** (String): this will be the color of the icon or the background-color for the list element; depends on `page_color_background`, valid values are any css hex colors like "#a5011c"

  **page_02_color_text** (String): if set, the text color will be changed to this

  **page_03_menu** (Checkbox): checked == `page_icon` will be shown; else only the title of the page

  **page_04_icon_only_menu** (Checkbox): checked == only icon will be shown, title not (not needed for my question, I use this only in the main menu)

  **page_05_color_background** (Checkbox): if checked `page_color` is used as background color for this list element, if not the icon will get the colored with `page_color`; if `page_color` is not set at all neither icon or the background will get an color

I am very new to Typo3, but I actually get the above code work with the normal header menu on my page. It was a hard way there but that part works. For the header menu I could do it in FLUID, but this is now a lib and I need to do the same here but with TypoScript - no matter what I try I coudn't get it right. Most examples and how-tos rely on "if uid = 1..25" do something else. But I need multiple if elses for this. I think how I've done in FLUID is the right way, now trying to get the same logic to TypoScript... and ended up here.

[Page Template Fields in Mask](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qA0uW.png)
This is how I added the fields in Mask

[Content-Fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dcABU.png)
Pages -> Edit -> Content-Fields (of Mask-Fields)

[Main Menu Bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bbAhT.png)
This is what I've done with FLUID (the main menu bar). Icon-only + Icon and Title + Title only.

Spoken in simple PHP logic I would do the following (just to explain the main thinking / way I try in TypoScript):

```php
    // dont need to check if page_01_icon is set: field is required
    // dont need to check if page_03_menu is checked: icons in this typo3 lib will always be displayed
    // just assume that $title holds the title and $url the url to that page

    foreach(....) {
      // save html/css code in var for text color if a color is set
      if(isset($page_02_color_text)) {
        $textColorHTML = ' style="color' . $page_02_color_text . '"';
      } else {
        $textColorHTML = '';
      }

      // save html/css code in background of <li> if background-checkbox is checked and a color is set
      if ($page_05_color_background == 1 && isset(page_02_color)) {
        $liBackgroundHTML = ' style="background-color:' . $page_05_color_background . '"';
      } else {
        $liBackgroundHTML = '';
      }

      echo '<li' . $liBackgroundHTML . '><a href="' . $url . '" ' . $textColorHTML . '><i class="' . $page_01_icon . '"></i> ' . $title . </a></li>';
    }
```

Basicly thats what I tryied to try in TypoScript :)

What I "have":

A Mask template-file with the following content:

```
<f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.linkListAuto" data="{data}" />
```

The lib.linkListAuto-file:

This is the default version without the php logic from above. here I need to "translate" the php logic into.. I couldn't even post a half way woring script cuz everything I#ve tried ended as the wrong way :/

```
lib.linkListAuto = COA
lib.linkListAuto {
    1 = HMENU
    1 {
        special = directory
        special.value.field = tx_mask_link_root_id

        wrap = <ul class="list-group">|</ul>
        stdWrap.if.isTrue.data = register:count_menuItems

        1 = TMENU
        1 {
            NO = 1
            NO {
                allWrap = <li class="list-group-item">|</li>
                stdWrap.htmlSpecialChars = 1
                ATagTitle.field = description // subtitle // title
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How can I say in TypoScript "render this way every link (sub-page) that comes",

but if a color ist set and the checkbox for use_color_as_background ist checked: change the rendering for this entry and give the `<li>` a background-color

also change the text color if it is set

and finaly add the icon in front of the page-title

**?**

Please help with ideas that dont come up with "if uid equals X"-examples. Had enough of them, they work, yes, but I cant change them to what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to understand the concept of TypoScript.
So the name may be misleading. TypoScript is not a scripting language but a configuration language. So you can't use the concept of a sequential computation.

In this way you configure your rendering.

Anyway you can add some logic to the rendering in the form of the `.stdWrap.if` function which can control whether a value is printed in the output.

The other important functionality is string concatenation: in TypoScript you can use `COA`s (Content Object Array) to build up a string where you decide for each array element how it is displayed.

For building up the string `<li' . $liBackgroundHTML . '><a href="' . $url . '" ' . $textColorHTML . '><i class="' . $page_01_icon . '"></i> ' . $title . </a></li>` you might use something like:

```
temp.li_tag = COA
temp.li_tag {
    10 = TEXT
    10.value = <li

    // if ($page_05_color_background == 1 && isset(page_02_color)) {
    //   $liBackgroundHTML = ' style="background-color:' . $page_05_color_background . '"';
    // } else {
    //   $liBackgroundHTML = '';
    // }
    20 = TEXT
    20.field = page_05_color_background
    20.noTrimWrap = | style="background-color:|"|
    20.if.isTrue.field = page_02_color

    30 = TEXT
    30.value = ><a href="

    40 = TEXT
    40.field = title
    40.dataWrap = <i class="{field.page_01_icon}"></i>&nbsp;|
    40.stdWrap.typolink {
       parameter.field = uid

       // if(isset($page_02_color_text)) {
       //   $textColorHTML = ' style="color' . $page_02_color_text . '"';
       // } else {
       //   $textColorHTML = '';
       // }
       ATagParams.cObject = TEXT
       ATagParams.cObject {
         field = page_02_color_text
         wrap = style="color|"
         if.isTrue.field = page_02_color_text
       } 
    }

    50 = TEXT
    50.value = </li>
}
```

Comment: OK, I "understand" what you did there, but for this I think I am to new to Typo3. Gonna try furthermore to get it running but I think I will push it to the end of the project (with the hope that I understand Typo3 better)

Comment: TypoScript is not so easy, but very powerful. As an alternative you might try building menues with fluid: try a menuprocessor.